# Merge multiple <td> into 1 with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a wide data table with 5 columns, when the user clicks on "print" link, the table should combine the content from 3rd and 4th td into 1 td to save space.

```
<table>
<thead>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Please help.

Comment: in other words, the table would have 1 less column. I have no idea for to do the looping with jQuery..

Comment: Your cells in the `<thead>` are missing their parent `<tr>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("tr td:nth-child(3)").each(function()
{
    var t = $(this);
    var n = t.next();
    t.html(t.html() + n.html());
    n.remove();
});
```

Comment: @user666923, Nico: Don't get in the habit of destroying DOM nodes by generating and regenerating `HTML` markup. You should be thinking in terms of moving DOM nodes around. This won't be a big deal in the simplest cases, but it's a destructive approach that could cause issues later

Comment: I like your approach, but aren't you also removing the nodes, essentially doing the same?

Comment: @Nico: The important thing to remember is that there isn't any HTML on the client side. There's only DOM nodes that are generated after the HTML has been parsed. After that, the original HTML is discarded. So when you do `t.html() + n.html()`, you're really asking the browser to analyze any nested DOM nodes under `t` and `n`, and based on that analysis, create and return a new HTML string. Then when you do `t.html(/* the resulting string */)`, you're now asking the browser to parse that HTML string that was just created, make brand new DOM nodes from it, destroy the existing nodes...

Comment: ...under `t`, and insert the new nodes. And then of course `n.remove()` will remove the old nodes from `n`. So all the nodes that were originally there are destroyed, and replaced with identical new ones after a fairly expensive process. But there's more. If the old nodes had any data or handlers associated with them, it will be lost, since that information is not carried over when the new HTML strings were constructed. In simple cases as the example in the question, it isn't a big deal, but that sort of HTML manipulation on the client shouldn't be done as a regular approach.

Comment: In my approach, the nodes are removed, but then directly appended into the new location. They're never actually destroyed. Just relocated. ....(sorry for the long comments). ;)

Answer (score 4):

Quick and simple like this...

```
​$('table tr > :nth-child(3)').append(function() {
    return $(this).next().remove().contents();
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/3eDLS/

Comment: thanks, this is indeed very simple. but for a jquery noob like me it's not very clear haha

Comment: @user666923: You're welcome. It does use a couple techniques that most beginners don't know. I meant simple more in the sense of writing short, clean code. :)

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
$('table').find('th, td').filter(':nth-child(3)').append(function() {
    return $(this).next().html();
}).next().remove();​
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/TsA8G/1/

Answer (score 0):

This was a tricky one. Best I could do:  http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/HbPrw/

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('tbody tr').each(function() {
        $('td:eq(1)', this).after('<td>' + $('td:eq(2)', this).html() + $('td:eq(3)', this).html() + '</td>');
        $('td:eq(3),td:eq(4)', this).remove();
    });
});
```

(Err... I deliberately left the `thead` as is, but it occurs to me now that this may be undesirable after all)